# JS/CSS dropdown in an <ul> navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dropdown

I am trying to make a drop down menu under a button in a  navbar, but I can't get it to work quite right.

As you can see in the fiddle, I have a working navbar with the "settings" button (hammer + wrench), that shows the "dark theme" option.

Here's the problem: I can't think of a way to make the "dark theme" option to be under the "settings" button since its inside the navbar, and adding the floating button to the navbar would cause some ugly effects (e.g. border and background color would not fit anymore).

[Link to the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3h8861da/4/) im talking about.
Heres the HTML for the navbar and the button in question below:

```
<ul class="navBar">
  <div class="divLiLeft">
    <li>
      <a>
        <button class="navButton">Button 1</button>
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="divLiLeft">
    <li>
      <a>
        <button class="navButton">Button 2</button>
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="divLiLeft">
    <li>
      <a>
        <button class="navButton">Button 3</button>
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="divLiRight">
      <li>
        <button id="dropButton" class="dropButton"></button>
      </li>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
<div id="dropContent" class="dropContent">
  <button id="change" class="navButton"></button>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS in question:

```
    .navBar,.navBarNew {
      list-style-type: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0px;
      border-bottom: solid 1px #3E3D3D;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #747474;
      transition-duration: 0.4s;
      min-width: 100px;
    }
    .divLiLeft {
      display: inline-block;
      float: left;
    }

.divLiRight {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

PS: you might have to expand the window to show the settings button.

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/3h8861da/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.dropdown` class use `position:relative`, which is needed when we want the dropdown content to be placed right below the dropdown button (using `position:absolute`).

The `.dropdown-content` class holds the actual dropdown menu. It is hidden by default, and will be displayed on hover (see below). Note the `min-width` is set to `160px`. Feel free to change this. Tip: If you want the width of the dropdown content to be as wide as the dropdown button, set the width to 100% (and `overflow:auto` to enable scroll on small screens).

Instead of using a border, we have used the `box-shadow` property to make the dropdown menu look like a "card". We also use `z-index` to place the dropdown in front of other elements.

The `:hover` selector is used to show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button.

> Referenced from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

```css
.body,
.bodyNew {
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
  padding-top: 40px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.bodyNew {
  background-color: #202225;
}

.navBar,
.navBarNew {
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #3E3D3D;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #747474;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  min-width: 500px;
}

.navBarNew {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #44474C;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #101217;
}

.divLiLeft {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.divLiRight {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

.navButton,
.navButtonNew {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: #747474;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  border-right: solid 1px #3E3D3D;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navButton:hover {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: #747474;
}

.navButton::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
}

.navButtonNew {
  background-color: #101217;
  color: #44474C;
  border-right: solid 1px #44474C;
}

.navButtonNew:hover {
  background-color: #63666E;
  color: #0C1018;
}

.navButtonNew::-moz-focus-inner {
  border: none;
}


.dropdown {
  top: -48px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  right:9px;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 140px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
 background-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: #747474;
}

.dropbtn{
border-left:solid 1px #3E3D3D;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body class="body">

  <ul class="navBar">
    <div class="divLiLeft">
      <li>
        <a>
          <button class="navButton">Button 1</button>
        </a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="divLiLeft">
      <li>
        <a>
          <button class="navButton">Button 2</button>
        </a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div class="divLiLeft">
      <li>
        <a>
          <button class="navButton">Button 3</button>
        </a>
      </li>
    </div>

  </ul>
  <div class="divLiRight">

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn navButton">Dropdown</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

Comment: This worked really well, there is just one thing that bugs me left. The dropContent seems to align wrong (I want it to align along the right border). [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1vxsh5j/) Thanks in advance!

Comment: I added a fixed width to the buttons to fix it.

Comment: If you reduced right to 5 px or something it ll fix your issue

Answer (score 1):

You should add `position:relative;` to your div `.divLiRight` and add `right:0`
to `.dropContent,.dropContentShow`

Comment: I maybe asked wrong, I would like the dropContent Button to not be positioned with top, left, ... since that makes zooming in and out break the positioning. The optimal solution would be a vertical list under the settings button (I think), since it doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Just add more buttons (have [id] change) inside your div and  css code #change {display:block;}